# Code display includes horizontal scroll bar which hides part of the answer when text scrolls off to the right

Tags: bug

### Description of problem

When mousing over the last line (or perhaps footer?) of a code block in a question or answer, a horizontal scrollbar will appear which hides the last line of code. This scrollbar is necessary to see code that is hidden to the right. However, once this scrollbar appears, the last line is unreadable.

This occurs in Chrome 71, on OS X.

### Expect

The last line to always be readable.

### Repro

On this answer, notice no scroll bar appears until you mouse over:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19189879/142098

[image]

Then, mouse over the last line, and a scroll bar will appear, which makes the last line unreadable.

[image]